# My Projectiles Stop Shooting Problem How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

[image][VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/7c3f5c0f7b83efed85430f218b673f0e) When my player distance is a little farther than the knife they stop shooting at the player I am not sure why? How could I fix it and make sure it shoots where ever the player distance is. Like I don't want it to stop shooting when the player is a little farther away from the projectile  I am not sure if I have a range for it to shoot the player or maybe when my player scrolls
when it stops shooting at the player the shooting sound still plays but my projectiles aren't shooting and that causes my sound to keep playing rapidly.

This is how my enemies shoot:

```
        for shootss in shootsright:
            shootss.x += shootss.xspeed
            shootss.y += shootss.yspeed

            if shootss.x > 700 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 500 or shootss.y < 0: 
                shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))
                shootss.lookAt((playerman.x,playerman.y))                


        if box1.health > 25:    
            if len(shootsright) < 1:
                for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                    BULLET_SPEED = 10
                    start_x = round(enemyshoot.x+enemyshoot.width+-35)
                    start_y = round(enemyshoot.y + enemyshoot.height+-25)
                    target_x = playerman.x+playerman.width//2
                    target_y = playerman.y+playerman.width//2
                    delta_x, delta_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
                    distance = math.sqrt(delta_x ** 2 + delta_y ** 2)
                    dir_x = BULLET_SPEED * delta_x / distance
                    dir_y = BULLET_SPEED * delta_y / distance
                    distance = math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
                    knifesound.play()
                    if distance > 0:
                        shootsright.append(enemyboolss(start_x,start_y,(0,0,0),dir_x, dir_y))
```

This is the class for the projectile:

```
    class projectile(object):
       def __init__(self, x, y, dirx, diry, color):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y
           self.dirx = dirx
           self.diry = diry
           self.isJump = False
           self.slash = pygame.image.load("round.png")
           self.slash = pygame.transform.scale(self.slash,(self.slash.get_width()//6,self.slash.get_height()//6))
           self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
           self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
           self.speed = 18
           self.color = color
           self.hitbox = (self.x + -18, self.y, 46,60)
       def move(self):
           self.x += self.dirx * self.speed
           self.y += self.diry * self.speed
       def draw(self, window):
           self.rect.topleft = (round(self.x), round(self.y))

           window.blit(self.slash, self.rect)
           self.hitbox = (self.x + -18, self.y, 30,30)
```

my full code: [script](https://hastebin.com/penikatefi.py)

Comment: Put some `print` statements in the distance calculation. I suspect some value is going to zero (or close). Also add a `print` in the `move(self)` method to confirm the values are changing.

Comment: ok give me a second

Comment: it shows that they are moving even though they arent moving it keeps printing moving [image](https://gyazo.com/7b38a9214a07b28aa1ff0650a927f82e)

Comment: Please upload the png and wav files (just zip them) so I can run the game

Comment: alright give me a minute

Comment: I have uploaded the knife https://workupload.com/archive/T25cH5aY/start tell me if you want more

Comment: Please upload all the required png files to run the game. I can comment out the wav code.

Comment: alright give me like 5 minutes

Comment: sorry it took me a while here is all the file https://workupload.com/archive/Pnmy3PYP LAST THING there is a background music but I couldnt upload because it was taking long you could remove that part or add your own background sorry for the wait

Comment: I couldn't download the file (website error). Don't include any wav files in the file. I just need the png files.

Comment: k sorry give me a minute again

Comment: could you tell me if the mega link works because I havent tried this  before I uploaded the stuff here : https://mega.nz/folder/TlMwxABI#niFk6gDiJEdB4nbdE7gCpw yah nvm it should work *

Comment: Download worked. I'll check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen is 800x800, but the knife code is checking 700x500. The knife projectile is created but immediately removed from the knife list at the next loop:

```
if shootss.x > 700 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 500 or shootss.y < 0: 
    shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))
    shootss.lookAt((playerman.x,playerman.y))
```

This causes the knife flash but no movement for knives past 700.
After setting the check to 800, the knives worked correctly including sound.

Comment: So I change the 700 and 500?

Comment: Yes `if shootss.x > 800 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 800 or shootss.y < 0: `